# The import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs cannot be resolved

Tags: java, opencv

I installed OpenCV (opencv-3.0.0-alpha) and it works properly but I can't use that import:

```
import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

//      System.loadLibrary("opencv_java244");
//      Mat m = Highgui.imread("C:/Users/raj/Desktop/sa1.png",
//              Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
//      new LoadImage("C:/Users/raj/Desktop/dst1.jpg", m);
    }
}
```

I get this error

> The import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs cannot be resolved

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you have the proper libraries in your classpath?

Comment: I have opencv-2.4.1 jar in my library .

Comment: @SagorAhmed and you are not suspicious that the jar is a major release behind to the installation you claim you have? Also which native-library are you using the x64 or x86 one?

Comment: I do not understand your comment

Comment: @SagorAhmed You say you use OpenCV 3.0.0 but your jar is OpenCV 2.4.1. The reason this is important is because they changed the functionality of Highgui (not used in OpenCV 3.0.0 anymore)

Comment: And while you're installing new stuff, please install OpenCV 3.1. Version 3.0 alpha is, well, an alpha.... Use a stable release

Answer (score 10):

OpenCV 3.0.0 is using the import:

```
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
```

However the library you are using (OpenCV 2.4.1) is using different import for the same functionalites:

```
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
```

https://fossies.org/diffs/opencv/2.4.11_vs_3.0.0-rc1/modules/java/android_test/src/org/opencv/test/highgui/HighguiTest.java-diff.html

Basically you are trying to import something that doesn't exist in the version you are using.

Now you can either use Highgui or get the jar for OpenCV 3.1.x